# Translate Exiftool command to C++

Tags: c++, exiftool

I want to translate the following exiftool command to an Exiftool C++ code:

```
exiftool -RawThermalImage -b imageIn.jpg > imageOut.png
```

So far I have written the following:

```
ExifTool* imageIn = new ExifTool();
TagInfo* information = imageIn->ImageInfo(imageIn.jpg, "-RawThermalImage -b");
```

Therefore, I am just left with the `> imageOut.png` part.
But I am not able to figure out how to translate this.
Can someone guide me towards this. Thanks.

Comment: Try `GetOutput()` to get the result as string and write its content  to file: https://exiftool.org/cpp_exiftool/#GetOutput

Comment: Oh, my bad, there is a c++ wrapper for Exiftool. Good catch.

Comment: @leosh Thank you. I will be able to get the content in 'information' through `imageIn->GetOutput()`. But how do I create a PNG file from that?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that `agInfo* information = imageIn->ImageInfo(imageIn.jpg, "-RawThermalImage -b")` doesn't work. I get the error saying -RawThermalImage is an invalid tag. 

Do you know how I can access the rawthermal values?

Comment: The `RawThermalImage` will either be stored as raw data or as a PNG in the file.  If it is raw data, then exiftool will make it into a tiff upon extraction.  If it's a PNG, then exiftool will extract it as is.  You can check `RawThermalImageType` to see which.  See [FLIR RawData Tags](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/FLIR.html#RawData).

Comment: Also, make sure you read the [`ImageInfo` inputs section](https://exiftool.org/cpp_exiftool/#ImageInfo) carefully.  I believe that your actual error is `-RawThermalImage -b` (space included) doesn't exist, not `-RawThermalImage` doesn't exist.  You need a new line between `-RawThermalImage` and `-b`.